# IRC bot in python won't send messages

Tags: python, irc

I'm using [Phredds Irc bot](http://pastebin.com/r1LtgEKC) because I am trying to make a bot for my twitch chat. It connects and responds to pings fine but it won't respond to anything else. I seem to be doing exactly what he did in the pastebin so what is wrong with this?

```
import socket #imports module allowing connection to IRC
import threading #imports module allowing timing functions

#sets variables for connection to twitch chat
bot_owner = 'TwitchPlaysFightingGames'
nick = 'MagicalCakeBot'
channel = '#TwitchPlaysFightingGames'
server = 'irc.twitch.tv'
password = 'oauth:~redacted~'

queue = 0 #sets variable for anti-spam queue functionality

irc = socket.socket()
irc.connect((server, 6667)) #connects to the server

#sends variables for connection to twitch chat
irc.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')
irc.send('USER ' + nick + ' 0 * :' + bot_owner + '\r\n')
irc.send('NICK ' + nick + '\r\n')
irc.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n') 

def message(msg): #function for sending messages to the IRC chat
    global queue
    queue = queue + 1
    print queue
    if queue < 20: #ensures does not send >20 msgs per 30 seconds.
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :' + msg + '\r\n')
    else:
        print 'Message deleted'

def queuetimer(): #function for resetting the queue every 30 seconds
    global queue
    print 'queue reset'
    queue = 0
    threading.Timer(30,queuetimer).start()
queuetimer()

while True:
    data = irc.recv(1204) #gets output from IRC server
    user = data.split(':')[1]
    user = user.split('!')[0] #determines the sender of the messages
    print data

    if data.find('PING') != -1:
        irc.send(data.replace('PING', 'PONG')) #responds to PINGS from the server
    if data.find('!test') != -1: #!test command
        message('Hi')
```

Comment: Where is the function `message` defined?

Comment: Edited,still doesn't work

Comment: If an answer helps you resolve your issue, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I glanced over your implementation and it looks like it should work (in most practical cases) now that you have edited it to contain the `message` function definition. I briefly tested the implementation you posted after your edit and it worked for me during two test runs.

Although it worked for me, I would not say that it is completely foolproof as is. When I tested it, I tested it in a quiet channel that was not flooding the socket with a high volume of data. Judging by the name of the channel you included in your code (`"#TwitchPlaysFightingGames"`), I suspect that you may be joining this rudimentary Twitch IRC client into a channel that is continuously pushing a high volume of data. The case I am about to describe touches on why this might be an issue for you.

### Divided Message Issue

The one obvious problem I see involves how you are handling the data you are receiving from your call to `socket.recv()`. Your code receives a hard-coded finite amount of data per call to the socket receive function and then assumes that it will always contain one full "message", so to speak. In your case, the "message" you are interested in is `"!test"` Depending on various factors including the latency between calls to `socket.recv()` and the received packet length(s), it is possible for your "message"-inspection logic to fail when a single "message" is divided across two calls to `socket.recv()`.

In the following simplified snippet of code, consider what would happen if the socket's buffer contained the data `"[x][y:1]"`:

```
while True:
  response = socket.recv(5)
  if response.find("[y:1]") != -1:
    print("success")
```

During the first iteration, `response` would be equal to `"[x][y"`. During the second iteration, `response` would be equal to `":1]"`. Neither of these iterations would contain the message `"[y:1]"`. In this example, `"success"` would never be printed. This is a significantly scaled down version of the problem I described above.

That said, if you wanted to create a completely foolproof implementation, you may consider building a separate buffer to house unparsed pieces of "messages". For instance, in the example above, if you parse the message `"[x]"` and keep the remainder of the receive buffer (`"[y"`) in a separate unparsed message buffer, you can later join the content of the next receive buffer with the unparsed message buffer to yield the full "message" (in this case, `"[y:1]"`).

### Potential `IndexError` Exception Issue

Another issue is that you are performing string split operations and immediately attempting to access an index of a list that may not contain any elements. You would know when this happens, because the attempt would raise an `IndexError` exception. I am guessing this is not happening to you, because you did not mention any exceptions.

### Advice For Debugging Your Issue

Because I could not easily reproduce your issue, it may help to have more information about your situation. I would start by testing the code in a quiet channel. Next, you should consider saving a second copy of the code and simplifying it so that you can narrow down the issue, if it still persists.

Consider removing the following code to simplify your problem:

- remove the call to `queuetimer()` as well as its function definition and any other references to the `queue` variable
- simplify the `message()` function so that it only calls `irc.send()`
- remove the `data.split()` and `user.split()` lines, since you are not using them

If you still cannot figure out what the problem is, post back to this thread with any additional information you uncover.

### An Additional Twitch.TV IRC Client Example

I figured it might help for you to see an example of what it may entail to take some steps toward parsing more of the Twitch.TV IRC protocol; so, I uploaded a quick demonstration application to GitHub with this in mind: see https://github.com/jwilges/twitchtvircclient for the demonstration code.

Comment: Ok I changed my code to [this](http://pastebin.com/29xi0VwP) but it still doesn't work. [This](http://pastebin.com/DWwm6TE2) is what the shell says when I run it

Comment: Based on the console output you've posted to pastebin, it looks like your client successfully connected to the Twitch.TV IRC server, authenticated, received the MOTD, joined the #TwitchPlaysFightingGames channel, and then received one PING message from the server. Based on the NAMES list provided by the server when your client joined the channel, it looks like your client was alone in the channel. Use a second IRC client and a second username to join the channel and send a message to the channel. I expect that you will then see your message appear in your console.

Comment: If you get to the point where you can see another user's messages appearing in your client's console output, your logic to send a message to the channel should work as expected. Any message sent to the channel by another user containing "!test" should trigger your client to send the "Hi" message as long as the receive buffer contains the entire string "!test".